# What is the proper regex for Active-Directory object's names?

Tags: regex, active-directory, special-characters

My application creates a SharePoint site and an Active Directory group from user input. Special characters that are mentioned in http://www.webmonkey.com/reference/Special_Characters becomes a big problem in my application. Application creates group names differently and application can't access them from name property. I want the user input to be validated from a regular expression for these characters. I googled in and found some good regex sampler and testers but they won't solve my problem. So can anybody suggest a regex for disallowing special characters which is a problem for Active Directory object names?

P.S. Application users may enter Turkish inputs, so regex should also allow Turkish characters like 'ç', 'ş', 'ö'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with something like this:

```
^(\p{L}|\p{N}|\p{P})+$
```

This will match:

- `\p{L}`: any kind of letter from any language
- `\p{N}`: any kind of numeric character in any script
- `\p{P}`: any kind of punctuation character.

When you query your AD, you must to escape some special characters, described here: [Creating a Query Filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675768(VS.85).aspx)

> If any of the following special characters must appear in the query filter as literals, they must be replaced by the listed escape sequence.

```
  ASCII     Escape sequence 
character     substitute
    *           "\2a"
    (           "\28"
    )           "\29"
    \           "\5c"
   NUL          "\00"
```

> In addition, arbitrary binary data may be represented using the escape sequence syntax by encoding each byte of binary data with the backslash followed by two hexadecimal digits. For example, the four-byte value 0x00000004 is encoded as "\00\00\00\04" in a filter string.